# MediaWiki API - Editing a page from Excel - <error code="mustposttoken" ...>

Tags: excel, vba, http, mediawiki

I am getting the following error trying to issue an edit command via the MediaWiki API.

```
<error code="mustposttoken" info="The token parameter was found in the query
string, but must be in the POST body" xml:space="preserve">
```

This is the code I am using in Excel:

```
 Dim objHTTP As New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
 URL = "http://wiki.address.net/w/api.php?format=json&action=edit&title=TestPage&section=0&text=testing123&token=" & strEditToken
 objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
 objHTTP.Send
 Debug.Print objHTTP.ResponseText
```

I have a separate part of the code where I log in and retrieve a csrf token. The code has worked before the most recent update to Media Wiki 1.24.1

Answer (score 3):

You're posting the token in the URL, while for security reasons it must be in request body.

Comment: What would be the VBA syntax you are recommending?

Comment: @Alex, I don't know VBA, I know MediaWiki:)

Comment: @Alex, does the official list of [web API client libraries](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Client_code#.NET) help?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by reviewing my POST from VBA. Set the user-agent and content-type. Also, lower-cased the title of the page in the URL string.

```
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
URL = "http://wiki.address.net/w/api.php"
strEditToken = "####################"
objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
objHTTP.SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
objHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
objHTTP.Send ("format=json&action=edit&title=" & lcase("TestPage") & "&section=0&text=testing123&token=" & strEditToken")
```